# Try-catch: is this acceptable practice?

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch

We have received Java code from a software supplier. It contains a lot of `try-catch` blocks with nothing in the `catch` part. They're all over the place. Example:

```
        try {
            spaceBlock.enable(LindsayModel);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

My questions are: Is the above acceptable practice? If so, when? Or should I just go ahead and remove all of these "bogus" `try` and `catch` statements?

To me this looks like terrible practice, but I'm not experienced enough in Java to tell for sure. Why catch errors if you're not going to do anything with them? Seems to me, you would only do that if you were confident that an exception would be of absolutely no consequence and you don't care if one occurs. However, this is not really the case in our particular application.

**EDIT** To give some context: We bought a Java-scriptable product from the supplier. Alongside the product, they provided a large proof-of-concept script tailored to our needs. This script came "free of charge" (though we wouldn't have bought the product if it hadn't come with the script) and it "works". But the script is a real pain to build upon, due to many things that even I as a Java novice recognise as awful practice, one instance being this bogus try-catch business.

Comment: Hey, that looks like `On Error Resume Next` :)

Comment: As a side note, unfortunately removing them might not be so easy, because of Java's exception rules. That is, you will have to change your method signatures to declare they throw that exception...

Comment: `Exception` or some subclass of `Exception`?

Comment: Swallowing exceptions is the single most terrible thing you can do in Java. Removing all the bulls* will take quite some and probably uncover many problems. Change the supplier.

Comment: "We have received Java code from a software supplier": I recommend not paying them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is indeed terrible practice. Especially the catching of `Exception` rather than something specific gives off a horrible smell - even a `NullPointerException` will be swallowed. Even if it is assured that a particular thrown exception is of no real consequence, one should always log it at the very least:

```
try {
    // code
}
catch (MyInconsequentialException mie) {
   // tune level for this logger in logging config file if this is too spammy
   MY_LOGGER.warning("Caught an inconsequential exception.", mie);
}
```

However it is unlikely an exception is completely meaningless in this situation. I recommend researching exactly what exception(s) the application's code is intending to swallow here, and what they would really mean for the execution.

One important distinction is whether the try/catches are used to swallow checked exceptions. If this is the case, it probably indicates extreme apathy on the programmer's part - somebody just wanted his/her code to compile. At the least, the code should be amended:

```
try {
   // code
}
catch (SpecificCheckedException sce) {
   // make sure there is exception logging done farther up
   throw new RuntimeException(sce);
}
```

This will rethrow the exception wrapped in an unchecked `RuntimeException`, effectively allowing the code to compile. Even this can be considered a bandaid however - best practice for checked exceptions is to handle them on an individual basis, either in the current method or farther up by adding `throws SpecificCheckedException` to the method signature.

As [@Tom Hawtin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725/tom-hawtin-tackline) mentioned, `new Error(sce)` can be used instead of `new RuntimeException(sce)` in order to circumvent any additional `Exception` catches farther up, which makes sense for something that isn't expected to be thrown.

If the try/catch is not being used to swallow checked exceptions, it is equally dangerous and should simply be removed.

Comment: Usually that would be at such a point that you wouldn't want code after the catch block from executing in case of such an exception. Therefore, you are best off continuing the throw with something like `throw new Error(exc);`. Some kind of logging is appropriate for exceptions where you will carry on executing anyway (for instance an event thread would typically catch all exceptions (except `ThreadDeath`) from an event handler and pass on to an exception handler.

Comment: @Tom - Agreed. The example was only for a hypothetical exception that was literally inconsequential and didn't warrant a rethrow. In reality I doubt this is the case. The OP should research what's being swallowed (checked/unchecked or just unchecked?). I just wanted to show that logging should always be done at the very least to provide visibility.

Comment: @Tom - On a side note is there a difference between your `throw new Error(exc);` and `throw new RuntimeException(exc);`?

Comment: There isn't much difference. `catch (Exception exc)` will catch only the latter. Generally it might be thrown a little further. An `Error` of some description is generally the right thing to throw if you aren't expecting the exception to be thrown (`AssertionError` may be better, but it doesn't have that constructor so the code will be a little over long).

Comment: "I recommend researching exactly what..." if a now-departed colleague had created this code, I'd agree. For a still-present colleague I'd punt it back to them and tell *them* to fix it. But this is "from a software supplier", so I'd reject it, tell *them* to fix it, defer payment until they had, and *never* use them again.

Answer (score 9):

Terrible, indeed.  Swallowing an exception like this can be dangerous.  How will you know if something bad has happened?

I'd feel better if the vendor wrote comments to document and acknowledge it ("We know what we're doing").  I'd feel even better if there was a strategy apparent in the code to deal with the consequences.  Wrap it in a RuntimeException and rethrow; set the return value to an appropriate value.  Anything!

"All over the place"?  Are there multiple try/catch blocks littering the code?  Personally, I don't like that idiom.  I prefer one per method.

Maybe you should find a new vendor or write your own.

Comment: There are multiple try/catch blocks per method, side by side and even nested.

Comment: I think that's awful.  I'd take that as a cue to find another vendor or write your own.  Sounds like they don't have any idea of how to properly decompose and structure code.  It does not bode well for their competence.

Comment: +1 for "wrote comments to document": there are circumstances in which swallowing some exceptions is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot just remove it, because it the try block throws a checked exception then it will have to be declared in the `throws` clause of the method. The callers of the method will then have to `catch` it (but not if the callers also have this `catch (Exception e) {}` abomination).

As an alternative, consider replacing it with

```
try {
    meshContinuum.enable(MeshingModel);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw (e instanceof RuntimeException) ? (RuntimeException) e : new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Since RuntimeException (and classes that extend it) are **unchecked** exceptions they do not need to be declared in the throws clause.

Comment: I'd suggest to replace the `RuntimeException` by a dedicated subclass of it (e.g., WrappedException`) and lengthy line by a method call like `throw wrap(e)` where `wrap` is a method declared to return `WrappedException` but actually always throwing it instead.

Comment: IIRC `throw e` loses the stack trace. It might be better to do `if (e instanceof RuntimeException) { throw; } else { throw new RuntimeException(e); }`

Comment: @AndrewPiliser `throw` is invalid, perhaps you are thinking of `C#` :)

Comment: @maaartinus just saw your comment. I like the idea of a `WrappedException`. Two years after my original answer I even think even a caught `RuntimeException` should be wrapped, so as to know the location of offending code that has an empty catch block

Answer (score 2):

```
    try {
        meshContinuum.enable(MeshingModel);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

This looks like unfinished code. If the enable method throws an Exception then it will be caught and swallowed by the code. If it doesn't then it does not make sense to try to catch a non occuring exception.

Check to see the methods and where their signatures are not followed by `throws exceptionName`, then remove the empty try-catch statements from the places they are called.

You can theoretically put try-catch around any statement. The compiler will not complain about it. It does not make sense though, since this way one may hide real exceptions.

You can see this as a sign of bad code quality. You should probably be prepared to run into problems of different type too.

Comment: Yeah, you bet I've run into problems of a different type, too!

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best:

- It hides evidence of the exception so debugging is harder
- It may cause features to fail silently
- It suggests that the author might actually have wanted to handle the exception but never got around to it

So, there may be cases where this is OK, such as an exception that really is of no consequence (the case that comes to mind is Python's `mkdirs`, which throws an exception if the directory already exists), but usually, it's not so great.

Answer (score 1):

What did your contract with the supplier specify?  If what they wrote, bad practice and all, meets the spec then they will charge you for a rewrite.

Better to specify a set of tests that will enter many or all of those try-catch blocks and hence fail.  If the tests fail you have a better argument to make them fix their terrible code.

Comment: We bought a Java-scriptable product from the supplier. Alongside the product, they provided a large proof-of-concept script tailored to our needs. This script came "free of charge" (though we wouldn't have bought the product if it hadn't come with the script) and it "works", so there isn't any breach of contract. But the script is a real pain to build upon, due to many things that even I as a Java novice recognise as awful practice, one instance being this bogus `try-catch` business.

Comment: The code looks like it is worth exactly what you paid for it.  Set up some basic logging, and stick it into every empty `catch` so at least you can see when one of them is hit.

Comment: "then they will charge you": whether they could would depend on the jurisdiction and the contract. You might (but I am not a lawyer) be able to claim the product was not "fit for purpose" or "reasonably fit for the general purpose for which they are sold" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merchantable). But it seems that the supplier was given no money for this code, so perhaps not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually ... not so fast.

There are legitimate cases for ignoring an exception.

- Suppose that an exception has happened already, and we're already in a catch(). While in the catch(), we want to make best effort to clean up (which could fail, too). Which exception to return?? The original one, of course. The code looks like this:

```
    try {
        something-that-throws();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        try {
            something-else-that-throws();
        } catch(Exception e1) {}
        throw e;
    }
```

- When we really don't care whether an operation succeeds, but (unfortunately) the operation's author throws an exception if a failure occurs.

```
    if (reinitialize) {
        try {
            FileUtils.forceDelete(sandboxFile); // delete directory if it's there
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
```

The above saves a rather tortured attempt to see if sandboxFile actually exists before deleting it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Horrible idea on the face of it, totally depends on what you're actually calling. Usually it's done out of laziness or habituated bad practices.