# Java - try block code

Tags: java, try-catch, block

Alright, so I'm working on a java program and I've basically got some code where, when I call it, I want it to **run if it would work without crashing**, but just **not do anything if it realizes it would crash**.

I haven't used try blocks much in the past, so I'm a little unsure of how/if I can do this with a simple try chunk. Note: I do not want to catch any errors (unless I have to for this to work). **I couldn't care less what error occurs, and I don't want the code to do anything if it finds an error**. I just want it to check for an error, and if ANY error whatsoever would occur, to not run the code, but if no errors would occur, to run the code.

I tried just doing this:

```
try {
   /*my code to run*/
}
```

but java demands a catch or a finally to be after it. Is there a way I can make a simple run-or-not-run without bothering for the specifics of the error that occurs in the try? Preferably without having to import more libraries.

Thanks!

Comment: `catch(Exception e)`? BTW, this seems like bad design.

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462750/try-catch-is-this-acceptable-practice) for why it is a **terrible**, **terrible**, practice.

Comment: "I just want it to check for an error, and if ANY error whatsoever would occur, to not run the code" <- That's not possible. Exceptions occure **while** the code runs. Your code doesn't know in advance if an Exception occurs. In fact: if the code knew what it's result would be before running it, what would be the point in running it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not recommend it at all, but you can use a empty catch statement like this:

```
try {
   /*my code to run*/
}
catch (Exception e) {
    //empty catch
}
```

It's not good practice to drop silently exception as they are informative. I suggest to log it in a file to make sure you can see them at later time.

As Edward Shen added in the comment, see [Try-catch: is this acceptable practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462750/try-catch-is-this-acceptable-practice) for a toughfull discussion about why it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

A simple try-catch would be sefice, just do something like

```
try {
    // Code here
} catch ( /* Exceptions that may be thrown */ ) {}
```

This way it will try and run the code, if it errors it will just ignore it. If you want to catch every exception you can do `Exception` in the catch.

Note: That you should not be ignoring errors, you should always try and find out what the issue is and find a solution!

Comment: He doesn't care about the exceptions - so `catch(Throwable t) { }` should be fine.

Comment: @MrRho if OP doesn't care about exceptions, then *catch only exceptions*. `Throwable` also catches errors, which you should almost never catch.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry for the mistype - he actually said errors.

Comment: Oops, meant to write Exceptions, not errors! I'll go for catching Exception like JFP said. Thanks everyone!